# Grails Spring Security - Manually Force Interactive Login

Tags: spring, authentication, grails, spring-security

In one of my Grails controllers I have an action that is annotated with:

```
@Secured('permitAll()')
```

however, in the actual action method it does several checks to see if anonymous access is truly allowed (sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't, depending on the parameters passed to the action).  Logically it makes sense to keep this as one action (instead of multiple actions with different access levels).  So I'm wondering if there is a way to manually trigger Spring Security to log the user in.  I could simply forward them to the login page, but that wouldn't forward them to the original action after they log in.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something I've put together from various sources.

In your controller class:

```
...
def authenticationEntryPoint
def authenticationTrustResolver
def springSecurityService
...

private boolean isFullyAuthenticated() {
    def authentication = springSecurityService.authentication
    !authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) && !authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(authentication)
}

def storeLocation(request) {
    def savedRequest = new DefaultSavedRequest(request,new org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl())

    try {
        Field f = DefaultSavedRequest.getDeclaredField('requestURI')
        f.accessible = true
        f.set savedRequest, request.getForwardURI()
    }
    catch (ex) {
        log.error('Error saving current request location.', ex)
    }

    request.session.setAttribute(WebAttributes.SAVED_REQUEST, savedRequest)
}

def yourView(){
    // Unprotected block
    ...

    // Start of protected block

    if (!isFullyAuthenticated()) {
        new HttpSessionRequestCache().saveRequest(request, response)
        storeLocation(request)
        authenticationEntryPoint.commence(request, response,
                new InsufficientAuthenticationException('You must be authenticated in order to view this page.'))
        return null
    }

    // Protected block
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation and I got into this post. Although I think Chris solution may be valid, my controller code would become less readable. So, here a simpler solution:

I created another action which requires authentication and added a code to redirect to anonymous code.

So, when your logic in anon action reaches a point where it should have auth data, just redirect to your restricted action. You just check for the user, and this will do the same thing that Chris suggested.

```
def springSecurityService

@Secured(['ROLE_MANAGER'])
def login(){
    redirect action: "list"
}

@Secured('permitAll()')
def list(){
    if (params.queryType == "confidential" && springSecurityService.isLoggedIn())
        redirect action: "login"
    ...
}
```